# Control Camera with Pro settings like in Lumia camera

Tags: camera

Are there any apps that would let us change ISO(preferably upto 3200), shutter speed upto 4 seconds , etc? Because , i really wanna try some long exposure photography on an android device.

following images are shot using lumia 520 at 4 seconds shutter speed.

[image: [![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaJHV.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaJHV.jpg)

[image]